# Die Bedeutung des Begriffs "Dicker Pulli" in Liedern der Fantastischen Vier

Tags: colloquial, slang

Vor kurzem hab ich mir mal wieder die (jetzt schon ziemlich alte) CD von den Fantastischen Vier angehört, worauf es die Lieder "Die Da" und "Dicker Pulli" zu hören gibt.

In dem Lied "Die Da" taucht der Begriff so auf: "Ist es die da, die mit dem dicken Pulli an, man?"  Ich hatte mal irgendwo gelesen, in dieser Redewende bedeutet der dicke Pulli, dass die Frau ein grossen Busen hat.  Aber jetzt kann ich online keinen Beweis dafür finden.

Im zweiten Lied "Dicker Pulli" scheint der Begriff zu bedeuten so etwas wie "Rüstung" oder vielleicht auch "Reichtum/Vermögen?"  Kann jemand hier weiter helfen?

Der Text des zweiten Lieds:

```
*Dicker Pulli an Mann dass ist wovon ich spreche
Meine Stärke ist der Sprechgesang und auch meine Schwäche
Ich mach ihn schon ich mach ihn schon seit vielen vielen Jahren
Und nach langer harter Arbeit komm ich endlich mal zu barem
Jetzt kennen mich die Leute fangen an zu diskutieren
Fragen dieses, sagen jenes, alles tut sie interessieren
Was geht ab was macht ihr jetzt was macht ihr dann

Hey ich glaub ich ziehen dicken Pulli an, Mann
Ich hab 'n dicken Pulli an Mann
Thomas hat 'n dicken Pulli an Mann
Andy hat 'n dicken Pulli an Mann
Dee Jot hat 'n dicken Pulli an Mann
Und Smudo hat 'n dicken Pulli an Mann

Es gibt so viele Dinge die um ein rum passieren
Man kann nicht allen gefallen hey das muss man akzeptieren
Mein Manager ist groß und schwer ihn nennen alle Bär
Und er hätte auch verloren wenn er nicht wie einer wär'
Denn hinter den Kulissen kämpft man mit harten Bandagen
Das Thema ist das gleiche man sieht nur andre Visagen
Über Image und Moneten was man will und was man kann
Deshalb hat der Bär 'n dicken Pulli an Mann
Ich hab 'n dicken Pulli an Mann*
```

Comment: Falls das eine zweite, nicht wörtliche Bedeutung haben sollte, ist die an mir komplett vorbeigegangen. Im zitierten Zusammenhang würde ich s als'dickes Fell"verstehen

Comment: Vielen Dank für die ausführlichen Antworten.  So muss ich leider eingestehen, den Beweis den ich Suche (für den Sinn den ich zuerst beschrieben hatte) gibt es nicht.  Ich weiss leider nicht mehr wo, wie, oder warum mir dieser Sinn in den Kopf gekommen ist.  Seid alle lieb gegrüsst von uns aus Virginia.

Answer (score 5):

Also als allgemeine deutsche Redensart gibt es den "dicken Pulli" nicht, das haben sich die Fanta Vier vermutlich selbst ausgedacht. Deshalb kann man die Frage wohl schlecht objektiv beantworten -- außer wenn es irgendwo ein Interview gibt, in dem sie das erklären, was mich überraschen würde.

Was es als allgemein bekannten Spruch gibt, ist, dass jemand "*ein dickes Fell hat*", das heißt, dass er oder sie tough ist, nicht empfindlich ist, nichts zu nah an sich rankommen lässt, sich etwas  nicht so schnell zu Herzen nimmt.

In dem Lied "Dicker Pulli" sieht es für mich aus, als ist so ziemlich dasselbe wie mit dem "dicken Fell" gemeint, nur mit der etwas aufgefrischten Formulierung vom "Pulli" statt "Fell". Die Fanta 4 reden davon, dass man mit mehr Ruhm mehr im Kreuzfeuer steht, oder dass der Manager im Musikbusiness mit "harten Bandagen" kämpfen muss, und da braucht man dann ein dickes Fell a.k.a. einen "dicken Pulli". Andere Assoziationen sind Schutzkleidung oder ein Kettenhemd (als Teil der mittelalterlichen Rüstung).

In "Die da" finde ich die Interpretation schwieriger. Es könnte einfach nur eine wörtliche Anspielung sein auf das andere Lied auf derselben Platte, also nur eine vielleicht gar nicht inhaltlich gemeinte Wiederaufnahme der Formulierung "dicken Pulli an, Mann". Man erfährt ja im Text nichts über die Frau mit dem dicken Pulli, nur diese äußerliche Beschreibung einer Frau in einem Raum voller Leute. Kann sein, dass (auch) ein großer Busen gemeint ist. Das ist aber halt auch die erste Interpretation, die sich so aufdrängt, wenn man das andere Lied nicht kennt und in die Beschreibung "die Frau mit dem dicken Pulli an" gern etwas reininterpretieren möchte.

Die Anspielung auf den Song "Dicker Pulli" kann man, wenn man will, auch damit in Verbindung bringen, dass es in "Die da" am Ende um eine "toughe" Frau geht, eine, die mindestens drei Männer gleichzeitig datet und sich von ihnen beschenken lässt. "Die Frau, die freitags nie kann", hat in dem Sinn also auch "nen dicken Pulli an".

Comment: "Die Frau, die freitags nie kann", hat in dem Sinn also auch "nen dicken Pulli an". -- Es ist aber nicht die da, die mit dem dicken Pulli an, Mann! Es ist die Frau, die freitags nicht kann!

Comment: Ja klar, deshalb ja "auch". Dass die Frau, die freitags nie kann, *im übertragenen Sinn*  einen "dicken Pulli an" hat, stellt sich ja erst ganz am Ende des Liedes heraus. Der letzte Absatz der Anwort ist ziemlich spekulativ, es geht darum, warum ausgerechnet in diesem Lied überhaupt auf das andere Lied "Dicker Pulli" angespielt wird. Du brauchst mir da nicht zu folgen, es kann gut sein, dass es dafür keinen besonderen Grund gibt.

Comment: Ich wollte deine Aussage gar nicht kritisieren. Du setzt da einfach noch einen oben drauf. Das ist in meinen Augen völlig in Ordnung, wenn es um Interpretation geht und zeigt in meinen Augen noch deutlicher, dass man es da mit der Interpretation nicht zu weit treiben sollte. ;)
Außerdem ist mir gerade aufgefallen, dass wir alle an der Frage vorbei geantwortet haben.

Answer (score 2):

Dicker Pulli oder Dicker Pullover, da würde ich zuerst an einen Pullover für kalte Tage denken, ein Pullover, der einen schön warmhält.

Comment: Jo.So hat sich das Mädel mit dem dicken Pulli an sicher auch gedacht. Leider kann sie gerade gar nichts zur Lösung der Frage beitragen. :)

Comment: @Olafant Bitte bedenke, dass DennisT hier relativ neu ist. Unabhängig davon möchte ich dich auch nochmal auf den Code of Conduct von german.SE (https://german.stackexchange.com/conduct) aufmerksam machen, darin insbesondere auf: "Be clear and constructive when giving feedback". Dein Kommentar entspricht dem nicht.

Answer (score 0):

Wie bereits von @HalvarF bemerkt, gibt es im Deutschen keine generelle Redensart "einen dicken Pulli anhaben". Insbesondere habe ich als Muttersprachler dabei weder die Assoziation "großer Busen" noch "Rüstung", sondern allenfalls "Schutz gegen Kälte".

Im Lied "Dicker Pulli" ist der Ausdruck größtenteils als Nonsenswortfolge gebraucht, die vor allem ihres Klangs wegen eingesetzt wird. Durch die Erwähnung des Managers, der "groß und schwer wie ein Bär" ist, erscheint ganz am Ende dann doch noch eine mögliche Bedeutung, nämlich dass jemand durch das Überziehen eines dicken Pullovers kräftiger wirkt als er ist. Das Anziehen des dicken Pullis erhält damit die Bedeutung, andere beeindrucken oder einschüchtern zu wollen, und die Aussage, ein anderer habe einen dicken Pulli an, bringt zum Ausdruck, derjenige sei in Wirklichkeit nicht so kräftig wie er aussieht.

Im Lied "Die da" handelt es sich angesichts des genauen Zitats inklusive des nachfolgenden "Mann" sicher um eine Referenz auf das Lied "Dicker Pulli" für Zuhörer, die dieses schon kennen.

Comment: I agree that in the song "Die Da" the fact that the unnamed woman has a "dicken Pulli an Mann" is clearly a reference to the other song "Dicker Pulli."  That is a very common conceit in pop-songs and Rap: to include self-references to other works/titles.  Still, the notion that "dicker Pulli" might also be slang for a "big chest" did not seem implausible.  In the song "Dicker Pulli" the meaning seems much more clearly about the F4 boys needing to toughen up, now that fame and fortune exposes them to criticism and other challenges.  Curious contrast: in "Die Da" they sing about being poor!

Answer (score -1):

Pulli steht für Pullover.

> Die mit dem dicken Pulli an, Mann

hat einen dicken Pulli an, Mann!

Da kann man jetzt 700 Seiten philosophischer Interpretationen schreiben. Die hatten die Fanta 4 sicher nicht im Sinn. Denn es gibt ja auch einige Lieder, bei denen tiefere Bedeutungen von Wortspielen sehr deutlich als solche erkennbar sind.

Insofern sehe ich nicht, wie sich

> die da, die da am Eingang steht

inhaltlich von

> [der] da, die mit dem dicken Pulli an, Mann

unterscheidet. Sie sind es beide nicht.

Das mit dem *dicken Pulli an, Mann* ist einfach ein guter Einfall, der rhythmisch sehr eindrucksvoll und inhaltlich - dem gesamten Lied entsprechend - witzig ist und den sie wieder aufgegriffen haben.

Man müsste die Fanta 4 fragen, welches Lied sie zuerst geschrieben haben. Selbst dann könnten sie sicher nicht beantworten, was du dir da alles vorstellst.

Vom *dicken Pulli* als Anspielung auf eine üppige Oberweite habe ich noch nie gehört. Das heißt natürlich nicht, dass es regional oder in einer speziellen Szene nicht als geflügeltes Wort vorkommt oder vorgekommen ist.

Comment: Das finde ich auch ganz witzig: das ich hier erläutern wollte über einer Umgangssprache mit dem "deutschen" Worte "Pulli" welches ja nur eine Verkürzung ist, aus dem Englishen "Pullover."   ;-)